# Installing .Net Add-in for POS 2009

Tags: deployment, wix, add-in, setup-deployment, wix3

I'm working on writing a WiX project to install a .Net Addin that is built for Microsoft POS 2009.  During the development of the project, you had to run the command:

> AddinUtil.exe -PipelineRoot:
>   {directory to the Addins folder for
>   POS 2009}

so that POS 2009 would recognize your Addin.  Now that I'm getting ready to do the deployment, I was wondering how this is done on during the install process, so that the user doesn't have to do this after they run the installer?

Do I just call the AddinUtil.exe from an Exec command during the install phase, or is there a tag that is available inside of WiX 3 that can handle this?  I recall several instances where I've seen other guys call external applications from WiX, and I'm just curious to find out if this is the best method or not for this scenario.

*Note: I'm basing this on POS 2009, but I think this winds up being a general ".Net Addin Installation" question.*

---

I should mention... the AddinUtil that I'm using is the standard .Net 3.0/3.5 AddinUtil that is part of the .Net framework which exists in %windir%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v3.5\ directory.

Answer (score 2):

I would just call a custom action.

```
 <CustomAction Id='Addin' Directory ='PATH' ExeCommand='[PATH]AddinUtil.exe' Return='asyncNoWait'/>
```